# Extract raster data based on a polygon's attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, arcgis-10.2

I have a land use layer with a map of the United States overlaid on top. I'd like to determine the percentage of different land uses in each state. Would the best way be to extract by mask by using each state and then calculating within each state?

I am very much a novice GIS user so any assistance/guidance would be incredibly useful! I am using ArcGIS 10.

Comment: I think there are a few approaches you can take to solve this.  Is this something for fun or something where accuracy is necessary?  What extra information can you provide to help narrow down which direction to do in the calculation?

Comment: If you've got the time then use a definition query in ArcMap to restrict to one state at a time and then use zonal statistics (as table) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w8000000 to create a dbf summary file that can be opened in Microsoft Excel, then change the definition query and run the same again to a new output table... then you just need to do some Excel work with each state. If you need each state by itself then use Extract by Mask http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002n000000 while each state is active.

Comment: Both tools need Spatial Analyst extension, if you don't have that extension then this isn't something you can do in Esri as the tools are locked out until this extension is active.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I do have the Spatial Analyst extension and I need to do additional analysis with crop land data on top of this so I think establishing a consistent method that I can replicate with additional data is key for me. And accuracy is important. I will try the zonal statistics route, but any other methods are extremely helpful. Is it possible to run this using batches and attributes? I have a Java background so I am thinking about it in that sense; perhaps that is more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Would you be interested in a python solution? p.s. if you put @ then someones name (who has already commented I think) in your comment then they get notified of your comment and (may) get back faster.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thank you for all of your input! I am attempting to run zonal statistics but I keep on running into errors with my input value raster (ERROR 000864): The input is not within the defined domain and ERROR 000863 Invalid GP data type. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are they in the same spatial reference? This ticket talks about that error http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39576. Perhaps the SplitField or input raster has floating point values.. Zonal statistics only likes integer, if this is the case then multiply raster by 100 (or 1000) and int() it then divide your results by 100 (or 1000).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Java background then python should be easy.. here's something that I put together:

```
import sys, os, arcpy

InRaster   = sys.argv[1]
InShape    = sys.argv[2]
SplitField = sys.argv[3]
OutFolder  = sys.argv[4]

# simple switches based on the output, change as needed
# note that python is case sensitive (true != True) so in
# the case of booleans False is a constant as is True
# but true, TRUE or any other combination is not
do_zoning  = False # do Zonal Statistics as Table
do_extract = True  # do Extract by Mask to create extracted rasters

# check out spatial analyst if you're running from a DOS prompt
if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
    arcpy.AddMessage( "Checking out Spatial")
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
else:
    arcpy.AddMessage( "Unable to get spatial analyst extension")
    sys.exit(0)

F = arcpy.ListFields(InShape,SplitField)
if not F:
    arcpy.AddError("Field not found " + SplitField)
    sys.exit(-1)

if not os.path.exists(OutFolder):
    arcpy.AddError("Output path does not exist")
    sys.exit(-2)

Values = list() # new empty list

# step through the features adding each unique value
# to the list such that we can then step through later
arcpy.AddMessage("Obtaining unique values")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(InShape,[ SplitField ]) as SCur:
    for SRow in SCur:
        if not SRow[0] in Values:
            Values.append(SRow[0])

for ThisValue in Values:
    # make a feature layer based on just this value
    defQ   = "%s = %s" % (SplitField,ThisValue)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(InShape,"Layer",defQ)

    # set output(s)
    outDBF    = "%s\\ZonalStat_%s.dbf" % (OutFolder,ThisValue)
    outRaster = "%s\\Extract_%s.tif" % (OutFolder,ThisValue)

    if do_zoning:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Zoning " + ThisValue)
        arcpy.sa.ZonalStatisticsAsTable("Layer",SplitField,InRaster,outDBF)

    if do_extract:
        # extract the raster using the layer to an arcpy Raster object
        py_raster = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(InRaster,"Layer")
        py_raster.save(outRaster) # save the raster object to a raster

    # clean up
    arcpy.Delete_management("Layer") # just the layer, not the data, so this name can be reused

arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial") # release spatial analyst extension (if running from DOS)
```

Have a read of [Adding a Script Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000001r000000) if you want to run it from catalog, otherwise you can run from DOS (cmd) window.

As it is written the code will do an extraction but not a zonal statistics, although the code is there I've turned it off with a boolean variable (`do_zoning`).